# What is the meaning of nomalized difference Built-up index？

Tags: geography, remote-sensing, mathematics, urban-climate

I know how to calculate it by remote sensing image, but why do we define this? 
What can we know about a remote sensing scene by this indicator? 
What's the connection between normalized difference Built-up index and Built up area?